# Prove complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove the following $$\frac{1}{z-1}*\frac{1}{z^n}= \dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}$$

for any integer **n** greater than 0. DO NOT USE ....

I believe that I can use mathematical induction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What would a proof by induction require you to prove?

Comment: I've done that basis step. 1/(z^2 -z) = 1/(z^2 -z). What i am having trouble with is the inductive step. Im not sure how to attack it.

Comment: Why don't you just multiply both sides with $z-1$ ? The series will [telescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's a proof by induction.

It is true for $n=0$
when it is
$\frac1{1-z}
=
\frac1{1-z}
$.

Suppose it is true for $n$.
We want to show that
it is true for $n+1$,
or that
$\frac{1}{z-1}*\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
= \dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{z^k}
$.

Using the induction hypothesis that
$\frac{1}{z-1}*\frac{1}{z^{n}}
= \dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z^k}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{z^k}
&=\dfrac{1}{z-1} - \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z^k}+\frac1{z^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z^k}\right)-\frac1{z^{n+1}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{z-1}*\frac{1}{z^{n}}\right)-\frac1{z^{n+1}}
\text{ (induction hypothesis used here)}
\\
&=\frac{z-(z-1)}{(z-1)z^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{(z-1)z^{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

and the result is true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
$\frac{1}{z-1}*\frac{1}{z^n}= \dfrac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}$

Multiply by 
$z-1$ and it becomes
$\frac{1}{z^n}
= 1 - (z-1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}
$
or
$1-\frac{1}{z^n}
=  (z-1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}
$.

But

$\begin{array}\\
(z-1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}
&=z\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{z^k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k}\\
&=1-\frac1{z^n}\\
\end{array}
$

QED

Comment: thx for the response but how exactly does this prove either side of the equation? What does 1- 1/(z^k) show?

Comment: That was an error. It should have been (and now is) $\frac1{z^n}$.

Comment: yep thank you so much.